# AWS Client VPN - Cannot resolve host

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpn

Since 6th Feb, our AWS Clients have been generating errors such as

```
2023-02-06 10:33:48.752 +00:00 [DBG] >LOG:1675679628,N,RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: xxxxxxxxxxxx.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxxxxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 (No such host is known. )
```

We have upgraded the AWS Client installs but get the same error. I also get cannot resolve errors in CloudShell.

Our AWS accounts do not have any support, is there a way I can raise this with AWS?

New client endpoints also have the same error

Answer (score 1):

This self-resolved. Possibly an issue at Amazon's end with DNS